# Nested for each cell in range loop

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook called the PCO report that I want analysts to beable to automate. It used to work but now the error "unable to get the concat property of the worksheetfunction class" I want the main workbook to compare project names with whats in the PCO report and concatenate notes columns for each project name in the pco report

```vba
Sub testing()
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   Application.DisplayAlerts = False
   Dim wb1 As Workbook
   Dim wb2 As Workbook
   Dim irow As Integer
   Dim ProjectName As String
   Dim COL As Range
   Dim COL2 As Range, COL3 As Range
   Dim ws2 As Worksheet
   Dim rng As String
   
   Set ws2 = Workbooks("Projects - Retail.xlsm").Sheets("Instructions")
   rng = ws2.Range("F17").value
   ' On Error GoTo Error
   
   Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\joshu\OneDrive\experiment\PCO Report.xlsm")
   Set wb2 = ThisWorkbook
   
   ' lastrow for assigned projects
   With wb2.Sheets("Assigned Projects - Retail")
      lr = .Range("A" & .rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
   End With
   
   ' lastrow for notes
   With wb1.Sheets("CL CA Report")
      Last_row = .Range("A" & .rows.Count).End(xlDown).row
   End With
   
   Set COL = wb1.Sheets("CL CA Report").Range("C2", Range("C" & rows.Count).End(xlUp))
   Set COL2 = wb2.Sheets("Assigned Projects - Retail").Range("B2:B" & lr)
   
   For Each col1cell In COL
      For Each col2cell In COL2
      
         If col1cell = col2cell Then COL.Cells(col1cell.row - 1, 38).value = _
               Application.WorksheetFunction.Concat(COL.Cells(col1cell.row - 1, 38).value, COL2.Cells(col2cell.row - 1, 20).value)
         If col1cell = col2cell Then COL.Cells(col1cell.row - 1, 39).value = _
               COL2.Cells(col2cell.row - 1, 21).value
               
      Next col2cell
   Next col1cell
   wb1.Save
End Sub
```

Comment: why not just use `=COL.Cells(col1cell.Row - 1, 38).Value & COL2.Cells(col2cell.Row - 1, 20).Value`

Comment: I tried that before but it just gives me an error message stating theres a type mismatch.

Comment: what are the type of values that you are concatenating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to diagnose this without seeing your data but my guess would be that one of the cells that you are concatenating the values of has an error value in it.

Try replacing the relevant line with this:

```
If col1cell = col2cell Then COL.Cells(col1cell.Row - 1, 38).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Concat(CStr(COL.Cells(col1cell.Row - 1, 38).Value), CStr(COL2.Cells(col2cell.Row - 1, 20).Value))
```

Which uses the [CStr](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/type-conversion-functions) VBA function to convert the contents of the cell into a String before you perform the concatenation.

Note that you can then, if you wish (as suggested by @braX), just use the `&` operator rather than the `Application.WorksheetFunction.Concat` function eg:

```
If col1cell = col2cell Then COL.Cells(col1cell.Row - 1, 38).Value = CStr(COL.Cells(col1cell.Row - 1, 38).Value) & CStr(COL2.Cells(col2cell.Row - 1, 20).Value)
```

As I said at the start of this, though, I cannot 100% confirm this will work for you as I have not seen your data.

Comment: So I guess I was trying to concatenate "#N/A" values so it was throwing an error. Once I put CSTR as you mentioned, the code worked perfectly! THank you